# Form hides on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

On my form, you have to select an item in order for the form to show.  The problem I'm running into is that on submit, it hides the form.  How can I correct that?

This is my script:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".orderForm").hide();


    $(".choice").each(function () {


        $(this).click(function () {
             $(".orderForm").show();


        });

    });

});
</script>
```

Here's part of the html:

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="choiceContainer">
            <@choicesSection><@choice id="2098885" class="choice">
        <label>
            <div align="left">
                <h3 class="choiceName">
                    <@choiceSelectionRadioButton />
                    <@choiceName>148PKI</@choiceName>
                </h3>
                <div class="orderForm">
        </div>
       </div></div>
<div class="btn" align="center"><@selectedPaymentOptionSubmitButton label="Continue"     
class="continue"/></div>
```

I updated the script too.

Comment: I'm going to guess that sumbit is reloading your page. You have a `.hide` right there in the `$(document).ready`.

Comment: You could also use submit() to handle submit. http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: yes, it reloads the page.  how can i fix that?

Comment: Use event.preventDefault() in the click function. I'm assuming click is what you meant by submit?

Comment: @Military911 Can you share a sample of the related markup for `.choice` and `.thisForm`?

Comment: I have the method as post but no action attribute.  I didn't create the form.  I was asked to hide the form and only show when they select an item.  I'm sorry all but I don't know code.  I'm trying to learn it.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, I'll edit the page with what you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sessionStorage (or an appropriate polyfill script) to persist a variable across page loads. (Note sessionStorage serialized the data so when getting the value it will no longer be `true` but the string `"true"`)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(!sessionStorage.formSubmitted)
        $(".orderForm").hide();

    //Reset it for possibly another form submission
    sessionStorage.removeItem('formSubmitted');


    $(".choice").each(function () {


        $(this).click(function () {
             $(".orderForm").show();
        });

    });

    $("form.form-horizontal").submit(function(){
        sessionStorage.formSubmitted = true;
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you. Now that I understand how you did this for the form, the credit card section should be the same way right since both are tied to the submit button?

Comment: @Military911 Hard to say since it wasn't included in your question, but the same method will most likely work for that as well.

Comment: I'm guessing there's no way to message privately, huh?